# ¿Por qué el resultado no es el correcto en esta consulta simple?

Tags: sql

Muy buenas gente, ¿alguien puede decirme qué hago mal? A mi parecer la consulta está correcta, pero el resultado es el erróneo.

**Enunciado:** Obtener el nombre y apellidos de los científicos que trabajan en algún proyecto con el científico Segi Montalbán Puig. Ordenar por nombre, y después por apellido.

**Consulta:**

```
   SELECT cientifics.nom, cientifics.cognoms
   FROM projectes 
   INNER JOIN assignacions ON projectes.codi_projecte = assignacions.codi_projecte 
   INNER JOIN cientifics ON assignacions.nif = cientifics.nif
   WHERE cientifics.codi_especialitat IN 
       (SELECT 
              cientifics.codi_especialitat 
        FROM cientifics 
        WHERE upper (cientifics.nom) = 'SERGI' AND upper (cientifics.cognoms) = 'MONTALBÁN PUIG' )
   ORDER BY cientifics.nom, cientifics.cognoms;
```

**Resultado obtenido:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Resultado esperado:** Debería salir una tal "Carla Revilla Bosch".

**Relación de las tablas:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Contenido de las tablas:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado obtenido? ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado? Hace falta más información para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Editado. Saludos.

Comment: ¿En qué tabla de tu diseño coexisten `Sergi` y `Carla` en un mismo proyecto? Parece que está haciendo falta un doble `JOIN`. Y... creo que evitaría el uso de `WHERE ... IN ... SELECT`

Comment: A pesar de todos los JOIN que están pero no parecen ser usados (salvo para multiplicar el número de lineas), lo que veo es que buscas el "codi_especialitat" de Sergi Montalbán y luego buscas los científicos que tengan el mismo "codi_especialitat". Asumo que no hay más que uno, Sergi Montalbán.

Comment: Tu consulta parece simple de resolver. si puediera entender donde esta cada uno de esos datos en la tabla. Desgraciadamente, al no entenderse donde esta cada dato, es dificil contestarte. Trata de explicar donde esta cada dato de los que necesitas.

Comment: Alex, si hubieras explicado con más claridad y ejemplos la estructura de tus datos y su contenido ya tendrías una respuesta. Ni siquiera dices en el planteamiento de la pregunta cuál es la tabla que relacionaría a los científicos que participan en un mismo proyecto. Pones allí una imagen para que adivinemos tu diseño y listo... Conviene que facilites las cosas, que seas claro planteando el problema. O tendrás que conformarte con soluciones mal hechas o con el silencio de usuarios experimentados de SO. También, conviene que indiques el DBMS que usas (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, etc). Saludos

Comment: He editado la pregunta con las 4 fotos del contenido de las tablas, a ver si te pueden ayudar.

Comment: No alex. No el contenido. Que campo tienen los nombres que buscas? que campos hay que relacionar para saber los proyectos? tu consulta es tan simple como hacer un select de un IN, pero no puedo decirte de donde porque no se donde estan los datos que buscas!

Comment: No entiendo qué información quieres xD, ya te pasé toda la información de las tablas jeje.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aunque la información es algo difícil de leer, los joins son correctos, pero el problema esta claramente en tu subconsulta, la subconsulta debería devolver (como bien lo pides) los PROYECTOS(`projectes.codi_projecte` o mas al alcance `assignacions.codi_projecte` que deben ser los mismos) en los que trabaja "Segi Montalbán Puig") En cambio tu subconsulta devuelve su especialidad y... dado que parece ser que solo él tiene esa especialidad, y seguramente él esta en 2 asignaciones distintas, aparece 2 veces su nombre.
La siguiente consulta debería funcionar:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cientifics.nom, cientifics.cognoms
FROM projectes 
INNER JOIN assignacions ON projectes.codi_projecte = assignacions.codi_projecte 
INNER JOIN cientifics ON assignacions.nif = cientifics.nif
WHERE assignacions.codi_projecte IN 
    (SELECT assignacions.codi_projecte 
    FROM cientifics 
    INNER JOIN assignacions
    ON assignacions.nif = cientifics.nif
    WHERE upper (cientifics.nom) = 'SERGI' 
    AND upper (cientifics.cognoms) = 'MONTALBÁN PUIG' )
ORDER BY cientifics.nom, cientifics.cognoms;
```

P.D: Agregué `distinct` para que no aparezcan los nombres segun la cantidad de asignaciones que tengan, además me parece correcto agregar `AND NOT (upper (cientifics.nom) = 'SERGI' AND upper (cientifics.cognoms) = 'MONTALBÁN PUIG')` a la consulta principal, porque al preguntar "quien trabaja con" no parece correcto responder que trabaja consigo mismo.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, puse una tabla que no era cuando hacía el subselect. Un saludo.